# How to access response value from the httpclient angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using HttpClient to send request. I have make a service to send request.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders,HttpResponse ,} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  apiRoot: string = 'https://xxxx/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getQueryParam(obj) {
    let search = new HttpParams();
    for (let key in obj) {
      search =  search.set(key, obj[key]);
    }
    return search;
  }


  post(apiURL, params, data){
    console.log('Inside Post Request');
    let paramsData = this.getQueryParam(params);
      let CompleteURL = `${this.apiRoot}` + apiURL;
      return this.http.post(CompleteURL,data,{params : paramsData,observe : 'events'});
  }
}
```

In my component:

```
login() {
    this.admin.password = Md5.hashStr(<string>this.admin.password);
    this._httpService.post('/loginAdmin', { "name": "vinay" }, this.admin)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.success);

      },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
          } else {
            console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

In my component i want to access response body value but it gives me error that "Property 'success' does not exist on type '`HttpEvent<Object>`'".i have checked on google some making a interface. but "res.success" can be array or object.
Please help me.

Comment: You can give 'res:any' if you are not specific about the types

Comment: [Reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: thanks Franklin that's resolve my issue, is there any cons of using type <any>.

Comment: Please Follow this  Link u will get more information  https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: And  here u ill get Demo https://stackblitz.com/angular/lynookokpqe

Comment: @MDGosoddin above demo code helps me. Thanks !!

Comment: @VinayMittal  thanks for ur complete please upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
login() {
    this.admin.password = Md5.hashStr(<string>this.admin.password);
    this._httpService.post('/loginAdmin', { "name": "vinay" }, this.admin)
      .subscribe(res:any => {
        console.log(res.success);

  },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
      } else {
        console.error(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

use ***any*** as the type, for the response that you are getting from the service.Hope that helps :)